# Plus construction is functorial

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, cw-complexes, k-theory, algebraic-k-theory

Given a nice map (cellular map) $f : X\rightarrow Y$ between CW complexes $X$ and $Y$, how is $f^{+}$ defined between their plus constructions?

Going through my old notes, I've learnt that the plus construction is functorial, i.e., $f^{+}$ is well defined because $\pi_1$ is functorial, but I'm not able to see how. (Its been a long time)

Also, if $f$ and $g$ are homotopic cellular maps, are $f^{+}$ and $g^{+}$ homotopic?

Are there any good references for this?

Comment: What is $\pi_1$ in thsi context? Fundamental group does not make sense here.

Comment: I'm sorry, its just some old scribble that I've done in the past :(. I can't seem to recall much :(

Comment: @PaulFrost The plus construction is an operation intimately related the the fundamental group (it is designed to quotient out by the largest perfect normal subgroup of $\pi_1$), so I'm pretty sure that is what is intended here.